# Is there a word for something that you put on a fire?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

In the sentence:

> He reached out to put more objects on the fire.

What is a better word for "objects". I was wondering if there is a generic term specifically for something that you burn on a fire. It is not necessarily wood. It is not necessarily fuel either. Think for example of someone who is burning "objects" out of protest or revenge.

I do not even know where to search for such a word. If you can give a resource where I can search for words by meaning, that that would be very helpful too.

Comment: [*Combustibles*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/combustible) is the only word that comes to mind.

Comment: I would stick to "objects" or "things," recognizing that the language quite usefully offers a host of specific entities destined for pyromasy. *(probably not a word, but should be)* - be they chunks of stovewood, political detritus, condemned heretics, or lumps of ground beef marinated in barbecue sauce.

Comment: I like @Mick's "combustibles," but take exception in the case of pots of noodle soup...

Comment: I think you should reconsider "fuel," or at least find something other than your "protest/revenge" burning as a reason to dismiss it. Each new object added in protest or revenge is "adding fuel to the fire" on at least two levels.

Comment: Perhaps, [pyre](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pyre)

Comment: I don't see how you can expect the same word to apply to fuel and, say, pieces of iron being prepared by a blacksmith.  It simply doesn't make sense to expect the same word to apply.

Comment: He is putting more "stuff" into fire.

Comment: @HotLicks:  One can put water on a fire, too, but the question isn't asking for a word for *anything* that one might put on a fire (including water, and nonflammable substances that you only want to heat).  The question asks for a term for something that you *burn* on a fire.

Comment: @Scott - It's entirely unclear what he intends.

Comment: Kindling? http://www.dictionary.com/browse/kindling

Comment: Can't you just say `He reached out to burn more <objects> (in the fire).`? Whatever you are actually burning can go in place of <objects>.

Comment: @alwayslearning +1 for this.  "Objects" can be the physical objects (books, records, flags) or can be a more metaphoric or descriptive thing ('heresies')

Comment: @HotLicks I’m going to disagree strongly with you. I think it is very clear what I meant. If such a word doesn’t exist, that’s fine, but I think the question is very clear.

Comment: Without knowing why the fire exists and why these particular objects are chosen to burn, it's impossible to suggest a reasonably "focused" term.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a modifier for "objects"?  Perhaps "sacred objects," "beloved objects," "objects that would get him executed in some parts of the world," "objects that [insert nationality] would fight for," "treasured objects."

Answer (score 1):

**Fuel** is typically something that you burn in a fire in order to extract energy (heat) from it. *Adding fuel to a fire* is a common phrase. (Incidentally, the idiomatic expression *add fuel to the fire* means to "make a bad situation worse", assuming that a fire bad because it is destructive.) A book may not be intended as a source of energy in this case by the burner, but it still works like fuel, so I think the word can still be used.

Answer (score 1):

How about [**burnable.**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/burnable)

Consisting or made of material that is able to be burned or is suitable for burning:

> ‘It consumed everything that was burnable, leaving behind only molten metal and frames of vehicles.’
>
> ‘People put out their trash, always conscientiously divided into burnable and not burnable, in an orderly way at the points indicated on the streets.’ (Oxford Living Dictionaries)